# Mysql timediff skips sunday and some hours of days

Tags: mysql

Need suggestion in mysql select query.

Circle Working Hours: `9AM to 6PM`

Case 1:

```
If ticket was assigned to circle at 5 pm on Day 1 
and was closed by circle at 11 am on Day 2, 
then time diff should be 3 hrs.
```

Case 2:

```
If a ticket is assigned at 7 pm on Day1, 
then timediff will only start from 9 am on Day 2
```

Case 3:

```
If ticket is escalated on a Sunday, 
then it's timediff will start from 9 am on Monday
```

Comment: Good One, Show us what You have tried as of now..

Comment: Will all tickets have trivial small number of days? Do you need to exclude also holidays? Do you need the solution to be done within database (or is it possible to calculate it in your program from given start/stop times), do you need to sort rows based on this value?

Comment: Done using weekday() and HOUR() function..

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce your own calendar, that only counts working seconds starting at some fixed date. 
Then you could do calculations as you would with normal timestamps and get the "working seconds" between two timestamps.

You would need a layer of logic that will transform real dates into the "working seconds measure".

You would need to decide if 
a) Day 1, 18:00h = Day 2, 09:00h
or
b) Day 1, 18:00h + 1 = Day 2, 09:00h

Lets use a) for the examples:

Case 1:

```
Ticket is assigned at Timestamp = 8 * 60 (8 hours since the start of time)
Ticket is closed at Timestamp = 11 * 60
time diff = 11*60 - 8*60 = 3*60
```

Case 2:

```
Ticket is assigned at Timestamp = 0 (would have to be convertd before going to db)
Ticket age is current Timestamp
```

Conversion could be accelerated using tabled conversion points for every year(/month/day)